# GKAgent Not Moving

Tags: xcode, ios9, gameplay-kit

I have a GKAgent on my project which I am attempting to move by having it follow a path. The path has been created along with its corresponding goals and behavior and it will move so long as I never set its position. Unfortunately I don't want it starting at the corner of the screen but if I set the position, the agent will not react to its follow path goal. Does anyone have any insight into this problem?

```
    let path1 = GKPath(graphNodes: path, radius: Float(2.0))

    let moveGoal = GKGoal(toFollowPath: path1, maxPredictionTime: 1.0, forward: true)
    let stayGoal = GKGoal(toStayOnPath: path1, maxPredictionTime: 1.0)
    let behavior = GKBehavior(goals: [moveGoal, stayGoal] , andWeights: [5.0, 10.0])

    agent.maxSpeed = 100
    agent.maxAcceleration = 50
    agent.radius = 40.0
    agent.behavior = behavior
    agent.delegate = self
    addComponent(agent)

func agentWillUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
    updateAgentPositionToNode()
}

func agentDidUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
    updateSpritePositionToAgent()
}

func updateSpritePositionToAgent() {
    print(agent.position)

    let agentPos = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(agent.position.x), y: CGFloat(agent.position.y))

    renderComponent.spriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(agentPos.x), y: CGFloat(agentPos.y))

}

func updateAgentPositionToNode() {
    let renderComp = self.renderComponent

    agent.position = float2(Float(renderComp.spriteNode.position.x), Float(renderComp.spriteNode.position.y))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the stop goal and I add it manually